# Refer to service in run immediately after definition?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-http, angularjs-module, angularjs-injector

I would like to attach a string from a `service` to every request. Attempt:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('main')
    .service('Foo', function () {
        self.bar = 'haz';
    })
    .run(function ($injector, Foo) {
        $injector.get('$http').defaults.transformRequest = function (data, headersGetter) {
            headersGetter()['X-Bar'] = Foo.bar;
        };
    });
```

> Error: [`$injector:nomod`] Module 'Foo' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Note: I'm using `ui-router` and have multiple files; but one `module`; if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the 'main' module? Because as the error message says there is a "missing" module dependency... (which may be just an oversight, since the missing module has the name of your service)

Comment: I am using [generator-m-ionic](https://github.com/mwaylabs/generator-m-ionic), the main.js is loaded before this service is defined. It contains something like: `angular.module('main', ['ionic', 'ui.router']).config(…)`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have `ng-app="main"` somewhere in your HTML because definitely the error message says that you are trying to load a module `Foo`...

Next, your approach is almost right. First, what should `self` be in the Foo service - use `this`. And also, why do you use the `$injector`? Just inject `$http` directly... your code then is as follows:

```
angular.module('main')
   .service('Foo', function () {
      this.bar = 'haz';
   })
   .run(function ($http, Foo) {
      $http.defaults.transformRequest = function (data, headersGetter) {
         headersGetter()['X-Bar'] = Foo.bar;
      };
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

My `$injector` approach was taken from: http://engineering.talis.com/articles/elegant-api-auth-angular-js/

Looking at the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http, here's how I rewrote it:

```
angular.module('main')
   .service('Foo', function () {
      this.bar = 'haz';
   })
   .run(function ($injector, Foo) {
      $injector.get('$http').defaults.headers.common['X-Bar'] = Foo.bar;
   });
```

Which works fine. Also, looks like I had another bug in my code which was causing the issue… that's the problem with coding at midnight >.<